# How do I uninstall iCloud extras on a Windows machine?

Tags: icloud

I recently bought a Mac for some iOS development, which of course requires an Apple ID and gives you iCloud. I wanted to move some files from my Windows machine to iCloud and saw that there is a Windows iCloud app so I installed.

Unlike Google Drive, DropBox, Box, or OneDrive, iCloud installed a bunch of other applications that duplicate functionality I already have, namely Calendar, Contacts, Find My iPhone, iCloudPhotos, Keynote, Mail, Notes, Numbers, Pages, and Reminders.

All I wanted was the cloud drive! How do I remove all this unwanted bloat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iCloud doesn't install other applications, it just provides the ability to set up sync services with your existing applications and those iCloud services. In iCloud Control Panel, turn off those services using the checkboxes to not use those services in applications.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but I guess it will have to do since it's correct. I had to uninstall it to get rid of the unneeded and unwanted integrations.